# A fibration $p : E \rightarrow X$ is trivial iff $p$ is a homotopy equivalence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

My question concerns propositions 3.2.5 and 3.2.6 of [Joyal and Tierney's lecture notes on simplicial homotopy theory](http://mat.uab.cat/~kock/crm/hocat/advanced-course/Quadern47.pdf).

My primary problem is with the beginning of the proof of the latter proposition. It is supposed that there exists a filler $k'$ of the given diagram, but I do not understand why it should. I have three ideas:

1. The inclusion $X \times (0) \rightarrow X \times I$ is anodyne. I don't see why it should be, while I do understand that $(0) \rightarrow I$ is a horn inclusion.
2. The covering homotopy extension property (Proposition 3.2.2) is used. For this we would need a monomorphism $E \rightarrow X$, which I don't know we have.
3. We are pretending that we have already solved the problem, which means that $p$ is trivial and thus such a filler exists by the fact that $X \times (0) \rightarrow I$ is monic.

Even taking this for granted, I do not see why it follows that we may assume that $ps = id_X$. Clearly $ps' = id_X$, but why would that also hold for $ps$?

Comment: The statement in your title is manifestly false.

Comment: Ok, that is how it is formulated [in this version](http://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Joyal-Tierney/JT-chap-01.pdf) out of which I'm working. There it is Proposition 1.5.6. Does it become true when X is a Kan complex? I'll try to work out why.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Could you point me in the direction of finding a counter-example? While it may be evident, I've just started learning abstract algebraic topology and don't see why the theorem should be false.

Comment: Never mind, here 'trivial fibration' means something else than what I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first point follows from Corollary 3.2.1: the morphism $p : E \to X$ is a fibration, hence the induced morphism $p^X : E^X \to X^X$ is a fibration. Finding a lift as in the proof amounts to finding a lift in the following commutative square:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
(0) @>>> E^X \\
@VVV @VVV \\
I @>>> X^X
\end{CD},$$
which exists because the right vertical map is anodyne and the left vertical map is a fibration. (PS: this shows that $X \times (0) \to X \times I$ *is* anodyne for all $X$. This fact is spelled out at the top of page 45.)

For your second point: it's not necessarily true that $ps = \operatorname{id}_X$. What the authors are saying is that instead of choosing $s$ in the beginning, you could have chosen $s'$. So to avoid carrying a $'$ everywhere they will henceforth use the name $s$ for what was called $s'$, and forget about the old $s$ altogether.